# VC++ 2012 Update 5 redistributable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I know this is typically a question for Google but I've been searching for a couple of hours now and still can't find the appropriate Visual Studion 2012 Update 5 c++ redistributable package. I can only find the Update 4 one. Is there a table somewhere that says which version of which compiler requires which version of which redistributable?

Alternatively, is there a way to pull the installer from Visual Studio itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft did not create another redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 5. The latest is for Update 4, according to [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003). Reading through the [release notes for Update 5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072098), it makes sense because there was nothing changed regarding the C++ compiler or standard library.

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't very clear from the site that this was the case or if that page is simply out of date - they should probably mention that somewhere

Answer (score 1):

According to [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003), VS2012 Update 4 redist is the latest available.